# Awk regular expression syntax with number of repetition - different handling between gawk 3 and gawk 4

Tags: awk, regular-expression, posix

I am having trouble understanding or explaining why the following expression fails in `gawk 3.1.x` and yet works in gawk `4.1.x`:

(Minimum working example)

`echo ";#ADCDE#" | awk '/#.{5}#$/'` -> produces a match in `gawk 4.1.x`, does not produce a match in `gawk 3.1.x`

`echo ";#ADCDE#" | awk '/#.*#$/'` -> produces a match in both

Did something change between gawk 3 and 4 in how regular expressions are handled?
I didn't think the repetition construct {n} was new for regular expressions. The same behaviour happens if I change the dot (.) with a character class or [A-Z]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding `--posix` works in 3.1

```
echo ";#ADCDE#" | gawk --posix '/#.{5}#$/'
```

I have

```
awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.6
...
```

From my `man awk` page

```
   r{n}
   r{n,}
   r{n,m}     One  or two numbers inside braces denote an interval expres‐
              sion.  If there is one number in the braces,  the  preceding
              regular  expression r is repeated n times.  If there are two
              numbers separated by a comma, r is repeated n  to  m  times.
              If  there  is  one  number  followed  by  a comma, then r is
              repeated at least n times.
              Interval expressions are only available if either --posix or
              --re-interval is specified on the command line.
```

Comment: Indeed works for me as well. The odd part is you don't need the --posix switch for gawk 4 but the man page reads the same. Thoughts?

Comment: and the man page states that intervals are only available with --posix, but my example is not an interval.... is this a `gawk` bug?

Comment: I haven't been following discussions regarding this, but it is probably mentioned in the Changelog for the library which does the regex matching. I noticed earlier in the man page, that it mentions it follows `egreps` regex's ...

Comment: @user153222 It says "one or two numbers inside {} denote an interval".

Comment: thanks for the comment. On the `gawk 3.1.x` system, `echo ";#ADCDE#" | egrep "#.{5}#$"` also works. Weird.

Comment: I found this comment in the gawk 4.0.0 changelog:
`8. Interval expressions are now part of default regular expressions for GNU Awk syntax.` [link](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-06/msg00013.html)
I guess that settles it.